# How to put a variable inside quotes JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select a specific audio element based on the key that's pressed.  The issue is the compiler is reading the variable as a string.  How can I get it to read it as a variable?

```
var hail = e.keyCode 
 var afile = document.querySelector("audio[data-id='hail']")
```

Comment: How do you see your code panning out?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your asking

Comment: `"audio[data-id='" + hail + "']"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```
var hail = e.keyCode 
 var afile = document.querySelector(`audio[data-id=${hail}]`)
```

Comment: This glosses over so many concepts OP is clearly not familiar with.

Comment: You mean the concepts that are explained in the link?

Comment: It still needs the quotes around the `hail` value.

Comment: @Amy - Not if it's a key code. Quotes are optional if the value doesn't contain spaces or a few other things: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attributes-2

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: While they're optional, they do get inserted in the parsed markup. I prefer to add them in (for consistency).